# Get datasource after applying filtering

Tags: infragistics, ignite-ui, iggrid

I am using igGrid, I would like to get the dataSource of the grid AFTER the filtering has been applied

I have found this link 
http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/79677.aspx which is helpful but doesn't answer my question.

This is the code I use to filter my grid

```
$grid.igGridFiltering("filter", filterExpressions, false);
```

Now I need to do something like this

```
$('#grid1').igGrid('option','dataSource') //but this gives me the dataSource before filtering!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the filtered data using the following syntax:

```
$("#grid1").igGrid().data("igGrid").dataSource.dataView()
```

Comment: Any way to get the data filtered but without paging?

Answer (score 0):

You can Get the filtered data when the grid have with pagination with this syntax:

```
$("#Grid1").igGrid().data("igGrid").dataSource.filteredData()
```